# Issue starting micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut

I get the below error when I run `./mvnw clean mn:run`. It runs fine with `mvn clean package && java -jar target/myapp.jar` but that doesn't hot reload code.

Any suggestions where I've gone wrong?

```
 __  __ _                                  _
|  \/  (_) ___ _ __ ___  _ __   __ _ _   _| |_
| |\/| | |/ __| '__/ _ \| '_ \ / _` | | | | __|
| |  | | | (__| | | (_) | | | | (_| | |_| | |_
|_|  |_|_|\___|_|  \___/|_| |_|\__,_|\__,_|\__|
  Micronaut (v3.9.3)

20:43:10.793 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Not Implemented
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Not Implemented
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$FullHttpResponseHandler.makeErrorFromRequestBody(DefaultHttpClient.java:2232)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$FullHttpResponseHandler.buildResponse(DefaultHttpClient.java:2194)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$FullHttpResponseHandler.buildResponse(DefaultHttpClient.java:2117)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$BaseHttpResponseHandler.channelReadInstrumented(DefaultHttpClient.java:2092)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$FullHttpResponseHandler.channelReadInstrumented(DefaultHttpClient.java:2153)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$FullHttpResponseHandler.channelReadInstrumented(DefaultHttpClient.java:2117)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.SimpleChannelInboundHandlerInstrumented.channelRead0(SimpleChannelInboundHandlerInstrumented.java:49)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:215)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsClientHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsClientHandler.java:180)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockFirst(Flux.java:2701)
        at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$1.exchange(DefaultHttpClient.java:499)
        at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$1.retrieve(DefaultHttpClient.java:506)
        at io.micronaut.http.client.BlockingHttpClient.retrieve(BlockingHttpClient.java:122)
        at io.micronaut.testresources.client.DefaultTestResourcesClient.doGet(DefaultTestResourcesClient.java:106)
        at io.micronaut.testresources.client.DefaultTestResourcesClient.getRequiredPropertyEntries(DefaultTestResourcesClient.java:87)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
        at io.micronaut.testresources.client.TestResourcesClientPropertySourceLoader$ClientTestResourcesResolver.getPropertyEntries(TestResourcesClientPropertySourceLoader.java:53)
        at io.micronaut.testresources.core.LazyTestResourcesPropertySourceLoader$LazyPropertySource.computeKeys(LazyTestResourcesPropertySourceLoader.java:98)
        at io.micronaut.testresources.core.LazyTestResourcesPropertySourceLoader$LazyPropertySource.iterator(LazyTestResourcesPropertySourceLoader.java:90)
        at io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySourcePropertyResolver.processPropertySource(PropertySourcePropertyResolver.java:543)
        at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.readPropertySources(DefaultEnvironment.java:430)
        at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultEnvironment.start(DefaultEnvironment.java:276)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:769)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:738)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.startEnvironment(DefaultApplicationContext.java:242)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:193)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:75)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:323)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:309)
        at com.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:8)
```

Comment: https://chat.openai.com/share/ca5fcab1-933e-481b-8136-ee87985c66f8